# Emails disappear when moving from Inbox to anywhere else

Tags: email, exchange, outlook, directory

Whenever a client of mine has a message open, they click on Move To Folder and the list of recent folders comes up.  That person selects a folder but the message does not appear in there.  What I have found out was that if I right-click on the message and move it that way the message will move successfully.  Or if the message is open and I do use the Move To Folder shortcut that if I select Other Folder and choose a folder they will move that way.  Which leads me to believe that the folders in the recent folders list point somewhere else.  So my question is, how can I find out where those folders point to?

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the actual email client and its server access protocol/mechanism is needed to lend effective/proper assistance.

If this is via IMAP, then you might take a closer look at the IMAP folders on the server versus the definitions/configuration on the client. There are server/client configurations where "hidden" IMAP folders are in use and (seemingly) duplicate IMAP folders may exist for an account.